# How to fix row height in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet. One cell contains multiline data. But when I entering this data the cell became very hight and I can't make it lower.

So I have situation like [image: this]
And I wan't to see something like in [image: Excel]

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is an option for this. See this Google support question: https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0D0fxOdOF_Es

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can select rows and set Row height. I have found this never works right or as expected.

The only way I have been able to get it to work consistently is by setting Word/Text Wrap for the entire sheet to Clip or Overflow. I prefer Clip.

**This workaround will look and read awkward if you set center-justify.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Spreadsheet does not support fix row height, I use **Airtable** dot com. Because there I can show only a row of lines even inside it has long posts or codes in the sheet box.

Then from Google Sheet, I use an Extention (**Airtable Importer by Railsware**) to import sheet from Airtable. One-way sync happens every 1 hour, though we can force it to sync when we want it.

I write on Airtable sheet but then use data on Google Spreadsheet. I know this is really painful, but it works for my needs to get CSV output link from my Google sheet.

Answer (score -4):

format / enable wrap / truncate

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit?  I get that this is referring to the menus, but that's tough to parse from what you have written.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. :(